# Google Pie chart: remove border around of pie slices

Tags: css, charts, google-visualization

How can I remove the border around of slices on a Google Pie Chart on mouse hover?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only *standard* option that will remove the border on mouse over is...

```
enableInteractivity: false
```

but this will also disable the tooltip

otherwise, you can override using css, the border is created by an svg ellipse element

it is the only ellipse with a stroke-width of 6.5, so...

```
ellipse[stroke-width="6.5"] {
  stroke: transparent;
}
```

---

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      ['a', 30]
    ]);

    var options = {
      legend: 'none'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```css
ellipse[stroke-width="6.5"] {
  stroke: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**EDIT**

when more than one value exists, path elements are used for the border, add...

```
path[stroke-width="6.5"] {
  stroke: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It will work for this case, but for more values border is visible again :(